# Why is a temporary char** argument illegal?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a function, `f(char **p)`, and I wanted to call it in the simplest way I could.

I tried

```
char ** p = {"a", "b"};
f(p);
```

and got:

> scalar object requires one element in initializer

so I changed it into

```
char * p[2] = {"a", "b"};
f(p);
```

and that went fine [*would have been also fine with just `char * p[]`*].

Why can't I create an array of pointers on the fly like the following?

```
f({"a", "b"});
```

Comment: Well, the simplest way I could imagine is `char *p; f(&p);` It depends on the semantics of the function if an array of strings is expected or the address of a pointer that shall be modified in the function.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This gives a warning:

```
char ** p = {"a", "b"};
```

because `p` is not an array.

This is also not legal:

```
f({"a", "b"});
```

since curly braces by themselves are not allowed in an expression (but can be used as an initializer).

It is possible to create an array on the fly like that using a **compound literal**:

```
f((char *[]){"a", "b"});
```

You could also use a compound literal to initialize a temporary:

```
char ** p = (char *[]){"a", "b"};
```

Unlike the first statement, this is valid because the literal is an array of type `char *[2]` and will decay to a `char **` which can be used to initialize a variable of this type.

See section 6.5.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for more details on compound literals.

Comment: Unfortunately, any compound literal created in such fashion will have a lifetime that ends with the nearest enclosing block, so given `int **p; ... if (someCondition) p=(int*[2]){&x,&y};` adding braces around the if-controlled statement would cause the object created by the compound literal to die before code could use it.

Comment: @supercat: I have to admit I was hoping literals like that would behave like string constants -- that is they really live forever and are in readonly memory. Oh well.

Comment: @Joshua: Or at least that they could be declared `static` and have such behavior, or last until code either leaves the current *function* or re-executes the literal.  Supposedly, the reason literals don't last throughout the current function is ambiguity as to what should happen if they're re-executed, but restricting them to a current block does nothing to eliminate that ambiguity.

Comment: @Joshua: So far as I can tell, the only common situation where the code compilers are required to produce for compound literals wouldn't be needlessly inefficient are those where none of the aggregate members are constants.  Rather useless, compared with treating them in a fashion analogous to string literals (yield a pointer to a region of const storage which may or may not be distinct from any other, but will hold the right values).  Too bad the only kind of compound literal supported by the Standard is the useless one.

Answer (score 15):

This declaration `char ** p = {"a", "b"};` triggers a warning because C does not know how to interpret the content of `{` `}` braces:

- Declaration type `char**` suggests it's a single pointer-to-pointer-to-char
- Content of `{` `}` specifies two items.

You need to tell C that you are initializing a pointer to pointer with a pointer to the initial element of an anonymous array by specifying a type in front of the braces:

```
char ** p = (char*[]){"a", "b"}
```

This construct is called a "compound literal". It could be used in a declaration, but it also works as an expression.

**Note:** if you are planning to pass an array like that to a function, you need to provide a way to determine the size of the array. One approach is to pass `NULL` to "terminate" the array, like this:

```
void f(char **p) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*p) {
        printf("%d:%s\n", i++, *p++);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    f((char*[]){"a", "b", NULL});
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/jYg1Gj)

Answer (score 5):

C99 and later added [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) for the exact purpose: *creating array and structs on the fly*
Example:

```
struct foo {int a; char b[2];} structure;
structure = ((struct foo) {1, 'a', 0});
int *y = (int []) {1, 2, 3};
int *z = (int []) {1};
```

Apart from std C99 and later, GCC provide this feature as an extension too.
In you case this will work

```
f((char *[]){"a","b"});
```

`(char *[]){"a","b"}` is a compound literal which creates an array of 2 pointers to `char` on the fly.

Comment: *GCC provide this feature as an extension too* - This (`f((char *[]){"a","b"});`) would not have worked on Clang?

Comment: @CIsForCookies; Clang also provide the same as an extension. In clang `int []y = (int []) {1, 2, 3};` will work too while GCC will throw an error.